# How to guarantee exactly equal size of faceted plots across different plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I'm doing something like the following. I tend to use `cowplot` for saving images of ggplot-generated plots but non-cowplot solutions are also fine. The first plot produces three facets (and one empty space) in a 2x2 arrangement, the second produces 6 facets in a 3x2 arrangement. I set `base_height` and `base_width` assuming a size of 2 square for each plot. In the images generated from the code below, the individual plots (each facet) are not quite the same size, across the two images.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~cyl,ncol=2) +
  ggtitle("hp vs. mpg, by cyl") +
  theme_cowplot(font_size=10)

save_plot("car1.png", last_plot(), base_height=4, base_width=4)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp))+
  geom_point()+
  ggtitle("hp vs. mpg, by carb") +
  facet_wrap(~carb,ncol=3)+
  theme_cowplot(font_size=10)

save_plot("car2.png", last_plot(), base_height=4, base_width=6)
```

I tried including the png files in the post but they each get scaled differently so it would be misleading.

I know I could generate each facet separately as its own plot and use `plot_grid`, and then `base_height` and `base_width` would set the size of each plot on its own, but is there any way to use `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` and set the absolute size when saved of each facet?

Comment: Would changing your code to read something like `facet_wrap(~carb + cyl, ncol=3)` still work for what you need? Or `facet_grid(carb ~ cyl)`? Or do you need to keep them separate?

Comment: In my use case I'm generating the two different faceted plots from two different data sets, I just want the resulting facets to be the exact same size. But it's true I could bind them together. Conceptually they make sense as two distinct plots though.

Answer (score 0):

Does `cowplot::align_plots` work for you?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl, ncol = 2) + 
  ggtitle("hp vs. mpg, by cyl") + 
  theme_cowplot(font_size = 10)

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("hp vs. mpg, by carb") + 
  facet_wrap(~carb, ncol = 3) + 
  theme_cowplot(font_size = 10)

twoplots <- align_plots(p1, p2, align = "hv", axis = "tblr")  #tblr' for aligning all margins
save_plot("car1.png", ggdraw(twoplots[[1]]))
save_plot("car2.png", ggdraw(twoplots[[2]]))
```

Comment: That is clever.

Comment: But unfortunately does not seem to work :(